# How to activate UISearchController in iMessage extension

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller, imessage

I have a `UISearchBar` in my iMessage app. A UISearchBar cannot become active in the compact presentation style, so when presentation styles change I want to request expanded presentation style and then activate the search bar. This is what Apple's #images iMessage app does. Here is my code:

```
func searchBarShouldBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool {
    if presentationStyle == .expanded {
        return true
    } else {
        requestPresentationStyle(.expanded)
        return false
    }
}
override func didTransition(to presentationStyle: MSMessagesAppPresentationStyle) {
    if presentationStyle == .expanded {
        searchController.searchbar.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

The problem is this code causes my `UISearchBar` to disappear. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Same issue for me, if I find a solution i will post it here

Comment: @RoaflinSabos can you provide some detail on how you set up your UISearchController? I'm glad to know I'm not the only one with this issue and I'm planning on starting a bounty to get more attention.

Comment: Finally I didn't use a UISearchController. I just have a simple UISearchBar and I have the same code as you. Everything works fine now.

Comment: I did the same. Really inconvenient though not to have the UISearchController functionality

Comment: Bizarre, I am using a regular UISearchBar in an iMessage Extension and the issue persists. Anyone find resolution on this?